# Configure the Spring Data Couchbase repository base

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to have a Spring Data Couchbase configuration.

Here is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.data.couchbase.repository" }, basePackageClasses = { BaseRepository.class })
public class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CouchbaseConfiguration.class);

  @Autowired
  private CouchbaseProperties couchbaseProperties;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
    return Collections.singletonList(couchbaseProperties.getHost());
  }

  @Override
  protected String getBucketName() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getBucketName();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getBucketPassword() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getBucketPassword();
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.EnableCouchbaseRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
```

I also tried with:

```
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.data.couchbase.repository" })
```

But I get the exact same error.

I also then tried with:

```
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.data.couchbase.repository" }, repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepository.class )
```

But I get the exact same error.

My Couchbase instance is running and accessible.

I'm using Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE with spring-data-couchbase 2.0.0.M1 against Couchbase 2.5.1 enterprise edition (build-1083)

The repository is:

```
public interface AnswerRepository extends BaseRepository<Answer, String> {

  @View(viewName = "answers_by_id")
  public List<Answer> findById(String id);

  Answer findByUuid(String uuid);

}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID>  {
}
```

Comment: have you tried having AnswerRepository directly extend `CrudRepository<Answer, String>` or even `CouchbaseRepository<Answer, String>`?

Comment: Reading the documentation, I understood I could not use the CrudRepository class since my CB instance probably does not offer the views matching the CRUD methods. I'm a noob with CB I must say.

Comment: So I just tried this: `public interface AnswerRepository extends Repository<Answer, String>` but it gave me the exact same error.

Comment: I now see I have a similar error when building another non dependent project. It gives me the following error: `java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()` This project would normally build.

Comment: The other project succeeds when going back from the spring-data-jpa 1.9.1.RELEASE version to the 1.6.2.RELEASE version. Something similar must be at play with the spring-data-couchbase project. If I could make this project succeed with the spring-data-jpa 1.9.1.RELEASE version then the couchbase project would probably succeed too.

Comment: I could make this other project succeed, by upgrading spring-data-commons from the 1.10.2.RELEASE version to the 1.11.1.RELEASE version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `CRUDRepository` as a base interface, or one of its child interfaces.

Also `Spring Data Couchbase` **requires** to have one backing view for CRUD operations to work. To additionally have paging and sorting (by extending `PagingAndSortingRepository`) or query derivation from method names, you'll also need a primary `N1QL` index.

Note that in the upcoming Release Candidate there will be an option in the configuration to auto-create the views/indexes you need, but it's usually safer to create them by hand since, depending on the number of documents already stored, it can be a costly operation...

Comment: Hi Simon, the issue is due to a dependency conflict. Getting rid of the 1.10.2.RELEASE version of spring-data-commons and replacing it with the 1.11.1.RELEASE version, solved the issue. I now have another error. Also, I would disagree with your statement that I have to use the CRUDRepository as a base interface. As I stated in a previous comment, I just cannot use it since I do not have the Couchbase views to match and respond to these CRUD methods. I also won't be able to dynamically create these views with a future release since I don't have admin access to the Couchbase instance. Thanks !

Comment: glad you could resolve your problem... it is true that you indeed can use Spring Data Couchbase without the CRUDRepository, but then the repository abstraction arguably provides much less value (if you must change the base class and write your own methods)... But there's always the benefit of having the template out of SDC anyway. Keep an eye out for Spring Data Couchbase 2.0 RC soon though, lots of new features in there!

Comment: I heartily agree with you. In fact, I had originally coded my repository based on the CRUDRepository base but quickly saw I could not make use of these CRUD method since my Couchbase instance is not providing the matching methods.

Comment: That said, not having the possibility of creating views and/or N1QL indexes is a larger problem that you'd need to address, IMHO... Note that you don't need administrative access to the cluster and webconsole, you can create views with the SDK if you only have the `Bucket`'s password if there's one (which you should have since otherwise you can't access data at all). See http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1-dp/sdks/java-2.2/managing-views.html